# CSS not formatting webpage?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do some simple formatting on a webpage using the following html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <Title>Publications</Title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="pub.html">Publications</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h1><center>Publications</center></h1>

  <p>
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <h2>TITLE 1</h2></a>
    <i>Published: ...</i> <br><br>
    <b>Abstract</b><br>
    ...
    <br><br>
    <a href="##" target="_blank">
      <h2>TITLE 2</h2></a>
    <i>Published: ...</i> <br><br>
    <b>Abstract</b><br>
    ...
  </p>
  </body>
```

with the corresponding CSS (located in the file `style.css`):

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
}

p a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: darkslategrey;
}

p a:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

However, none of the CSS for the `p` tag is being applied to the HTML. At the same time, the CSS for the `p` tag is being applied to other pages, just not this one and I don't know why.

Comment: By default, many browsers will only load a site's css once per day.  After the first time, they use a locally cached copy.  So if you change the css, the browser won't load the new css unless you do a force reload.  Perhaps that is your problem.  Try a force reload.

Comment: I have tried doing a forced reload and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Is `style.css` the same base url as this html file?

Comment: Please attach an example output

Comment: You've got some pretty broken HTML there — such as an `h2` inside a `p`, which isn't allowed.

Comment: I agree with @ralph-m. You can't nested block level element inside **p** tag including *p* itself. Already said in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p). I already answer this question, but disagreed by *@John Gordon*, so I delete my answer.

Comment: Taking the `h2` tag out of the `p` tag did fix things, thank you so much.